# how to write test for socket emit with acknowledge function

Tags: socket.io, mocking, jestjs, asyncsocket

I have a socket emit function which has acknowledge function as

```
socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', (data) => {
   const a = 5;
   this.sum(a,data);
});
```

I want to have a test that covers the line `const a = 5;` and `this.sum(a,data);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to testing easily, you should make a little refactor about your code like this:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { socket } from './socket';

export const obj = {
  someMethod() {
    this.handleFerret = this.handleFerret.bind(this);
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', this.handleFerret);
  },

  handleFerret(data) {
    const a = 5;
    this.sum(a, data);
  },

  sum(a, b) {
    //
  }
};
```

`socket.ts`: simulate `socket.io` module, you can replace it with `socket.io`

```js
export const socket = {
  emit(event, data, callback) {
    // real implemetation
  }
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { obj } from './';
import { socket } from './socket';

describe('obj', () => {
  it('should emit event and execute callback correctly', () => {
    const emitSpy = jest.spyOn(socket, 'emit');
    obj.someMethod();
    expect(emitSpy).toBeCalledWith('ferret', 'tobi', obj.handleFerret);
  });

  it('should handle ferret correctly', () => {
    const sumSpy = jest.spyOn(obj, 'sum');
    obj.handleFerret(2);
    expect(sumSpy).toBeCalledWith(5, 2);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57461614/index.spec.ts (12.977s)
  obj
    ✓ should emit event and execute callback correctly (13ms)
    ✓ should handle ferret correctly (1ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 socket.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.159s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57461614