# Use Jest to spyOn chained function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, socket.io

I am trying to spyOn a chained function for my socketIO server. The first `toSpy` is working fine but I seem to be unable to check the `emit` chained function.

Anyone a simple and elegant way to test a chained function in Jest?

```
const toSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'to');
const emitSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'emit'); 

expect(toSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // 1 times called
expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // 0 times called
```

```
io.to(id).emit('hello', {
    data: data
  });
```

Comment: Find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58152231/11561000

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719741/how-do-i-mock-and-test-chained-function-with-jest), you could provide a mock implementation to your first spy, which will return the object you're currently testing.

```
const toSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'to').mockReturnThis();
const emitSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'emit'); 

expect(toSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First chained function should return to pass the output from the first function to the second function. So that it goes around till the end of the result manipulation.

```
const toSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'to').mockReturnValue(<any-value>);
const emitSpy = jest.spyOn(io, 'emit').mockReturnValue(<any-value>); 

expect(toSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // 1 times called
expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // 1 times called
```